# Can I disable SpellChecking on specific Spans in EditText

Tags: android

I am extending EditText and add special words to the text from a list, programmatically. I am adding the text and also a Span (BackgroundColorSpan, ClickableSpan, etc to show them as different and make them clickable.

Is there any way I can disable spellcheck on a particular word or Span in my EditText/Editable?

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: No, it seems to be all (using XML attribute as below) or nothing. You would have to create some custom classes implementing Spannable I guess.

Answer (score 2):

to Disable spell checking you have to specify the EditText's InputType in your XML file as the following:

```
 android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Comment: That disables it for the entire TextView/EditText. I only want to disable for specific "spans" (ranges in the text) in the contents. Also, I think spell checker (red underlined text and suggestions when word clicked) is different from the input type suggestions you get above the keyboard as you type.